# Unable to paste file path directly from Windows Explorer to PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, powershell, copy-paste

I can't paste path to PowerShell window when the file or folder location is copied from Windows Explorer (select file > right click > copy / select file > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>). Bizarrely I can paste to the shell after first pasting to somewhere else, for example to notepad. Why does this occur and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how can you copy a file path by `file > right click > copy/select file > Ctrl + C`, but you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while right-clicking on file. It adds a new context menu item 'Copy as Path'. This should allow you to copy/paste the path to PowerShell or any other application.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: "I am not exactly how can you copy a file path by `file > right click > copy/select file > Ctrl + C`" — I've understood that this is normal Windows behavior?  Copying a file also copies its path?

Comment: @user598527, when you say *"I've understood that this is normal Windows behavior? Copying a file also copies its path?"*, that's not the case. The answer that Cricrazy submitted will provide you with that capability, but it won't work by default in the manner that you described.

Comment: @Run5k: Thank you for pointing that out, I have unaccepted the answer. I was absolutely sure that copying a file copies the path as well, as that's how copy/paste functions on my system :/

Comment: There may be a small misunderstanding.  The answer that Cricrazy submitted will work perfectly:  if you hold down `Shift` and right-click a file to utilize `Copy as path`, you can then open PowerShell and right-click within the window to paste that same path.

Comment: @Run5k: Yes, the solution does work, but it doesn't solve the underlying issue and as I said, I'm no longer sure how copy/paste works Windows by default... I may accept the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is worded properly and precisely, and the asker wants ONLY the path and not the full filespec, you can highlight the file in File Explorer, then use the "Copy Path" menu entry in the ribbon at top left/center.

[image: screenshot]